# How to acces to usb Stick with freedos?

Tags: usb, freedos

I would like to find my usb stick but i can't list it with " DIR" , do you know a command that could help me to find it ? i tryed to acces with "cd D:\" but it doesn't find it .
then, do you know if it is possible to run an iso file or to burn a disk with freedos ?

Comment: FreeDOS doesn't have native support for usb devices: you need to load additional drivers, and those may work or not depending on your hardware. And try to make one question at a time.

Answer (score 0):

FreeDOS and just DOS in general does not support the syntax of cd D:\ you would just need to enter your drive letter in this case D: and press enter, at the prompt and that should allow you to view the contents of your drive. As far as burning an image I am not sure why you would want to do that under DOS anyway, however I think there is a port of the Unix dd command available for FreeDOS in which you could write the iso files to a disc.

If you have already figured this out by now that is great! otherwise i hope this answer helps

Comment: Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.